# IoC/DI: How to inject specific instance when there are multiple implementations of same interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Assume we have two implementations of `IService` interface:

```
public interface IService { }

public class Service1 : IService { }

public class Service2 : IService { }
```

Then we have two classes which are depended on `IService`:

```
public class Consumer1
{
    public Consumer1(IService svc) { }
}

public class Consumer2
{
    public Consumer2(IService svc) { }
}
```

Now, how can I inject `Service1` into `Consumer1` and `Service2` into `Consumer2` using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) as dependency container and **without** using a factory or separate interfaces?

The generic pattern (not related to specific DI container) of how to archive this would be also great :)

**UPDATE**
I've already tried the context based injection with Simple Injector. The documentation is very limited and I'm ended up with the following code:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IService),
    typeof(Service1),
    Lifestyle.Transient,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Consumer1));

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IService),
    typeof(Service2),
    Lifestyle.Transient,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Consumer2));

container.Register<Consumer1>();
container.Register<Consumer2>();
```

but then I get an exception

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type Consumer1 failed. The constructor of type Consumer1 contains the parameter with name 'svc' and type IService that is not registered. Please ensure IService is registered, or change the constructor of Consumer1. 1 conditional registration for IService exists that is applicable to IService, but its supplied predicate didn't return true when provided with the contextual information for Consumer1.

I've tried with different variations of predicate but without success...

```
c => c.Consumer.Target.TargetType == typeof(Consumer1)
c => c.Consumer.ServiceType == typeof(Consumer1)
```

Comment: The answer will always be specific to the DI framework you're using. You are asking about "context based injection", which, for SimpleInjector is documented [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection). As you're interested in other DI frameworks, Ninject does it like [this](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

Comment: Check this: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection

Comment: Do you happen to have several interfaces with the same name `IService`?

Comment: "without using ... separate interfaces". Make sure that you aren't violation the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here, because if you do, the answer usually actually *is** to create separate interfaces.

Comment: Note that the `Consumer` property of the `PredicateContext` describes the 'consuming class of the current dependency' (or parent), while the `Consumer.Target` describes the constructor parameter or property that the dependency is injected into. So `Consumer.Target.TargetType` will (almost) always be equal to the type of registration (in your case `IService`). `Consumer.Target` is more useful for getting the property or parameter name or can be used to query for certain attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this problem with the latest version (3.1) of SI. This test passes:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.RegisterConditional<IService, Service1>(
        c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Consumer1));
    container.RegisterConditional<IService, Service2>(
        c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Consumer2));
    container.Register<Consumer1>();
    container.Register<Consumer2>();

    container.Verify();

    var result1 = container.GetInstance<Consumer1>();
    var result2 = container.GetInstance<Consumer2>();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Service1>(result1.Svc);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Service2>(result2.Svc);
}
```

What version of SI are you using and are you sure you are using the correct instance of the `container`?